# Android app to provide shortcuts for Words e.g usa for United states of America

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I want to develop an app for android, which will provide shortcuts for the words, e.g when i will type usa (followed by a space) that should get replaced with united states of america. Need help to know which class methods i need to override and how to invoke this app when keyboard pops out in any application. As i am a newbie so my question might sound awkward but thanks for the help in advance. (The iphone OS has a built in feature like this).

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  Some custom keyboards provide this functionality.  But there's no way to intercept data between the keyboard and the application.  It would be a massive security hole if there was-  it would allow for keyloggers.

Now if you want to add this to only your app, there's ways to do it.  But as a general work in any app thing, no dice.